# Angular animation: Slider Effect

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-animate

Have a look at the code here: [Simple Angular animation example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WNdrmy2VWFicj0vocGcp?p=preview)
I want to generate a similar effect in in my webpage using Angular animation. The only difference is, in the above example, the code is generating slider effect when fetching different html files. My project has a slight modification to that. Instead,  i want to display two different div of the same html file. On clicking button one I want to display a div. lets call it div1 for now. On clicking button 2 I want to display div2 and remove display of div1 by showing sliding animation. How do I do that? 
The index.html code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title>AngularJS Swipe Slider animation</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="tabsSwipeCtrl as responsive">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="responsive.selectPage(0)" ng-class="{'active': responsive.ngIncludeSelected.index == 0}">First</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="responsive.selectPage(1)" ng-class="{'active': responsive.ngIncludeSelected.index == 1}">Second</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="responsive.selectPage(2)" ng-class="{'active': responsive.ngIncludeSelected.index == 2}">Third</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="responsive.selectPage(3)" ng-class="{'active': responsive.ngIncludeSelected.index == 3}">Fourth</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ngIncludeRelative">
      <div class="ngIncludeItem" ng-include="responsive.ngIncludeSelected.url" ng-class="{'moveToLeft' : responsive.moveToLeft}"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Within div u can simply do by using jquery animate function

```
$(".btn-default").click(function(){
$("div2").animate({
    left: '250px'
});
});
```

Comment: Please have a look the code here : http://bl.ocks.org/anonymoussc/4f30d2563f5524ff618d

Comment: I don't need separate html files. I just want the content of each html file (firstSwipe,secondSwipe,.....) to be in my index.html file. I want these to be div in my index.html whose display property is set to none until the button is clicked. On clicking the button, I want the respective div to appear through an animation.For that part, I guess, I need to make some changes in script.js file in the   responsive.ngIncludeTemplates